# failed (104: Connection reset by peer)

Tags: php, nginx

We are using the php5-fpm and nginx.

```
    # nginx -v
    nginx version: nginx/1.1.19
```

```
*

    # php -v
    PHP 5.3.27-1~dotdeb.0 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Jul 25 2013 19:30:39) 
    Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
    Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
        with Xdebug v2.2.3, Copyright (c) 2002-2013, by Derick Rethans

*
```

Got the following error,

```
    2013/08/21 20:00:20 [error] 12740#0: *46 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 172.17.7.12, server: fe.test.local, request: "GET /search?gender=female&ageFrom=20&ageTo=32&religionId=&casteId=&countryId=&heightFrom=&heightTo=&profileImageStatus=%28y+p%29&search=Search HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "fe.test.local", referrer: "http://fe.test.local/
```

PHP5-FPM configuration,

```
    # grep ^[^\;] /etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf

    [global]
    pid = /var/run/php5-fpm.pid
    error_log = /var/log/php5-fpm.log
    log_level = notice 
    process_control_timeout = 30 
    include=/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/*.conf
```

```
    # grep ^[^\;] /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf 
    [www]
    listen = /var/run/php5-fpm.sock
    listen.backlog = -1
    user = www-data
    group = www-data
    pm = dynamic
    pm.max_children = 10
    pm.start_servers = 4
    pm.min_spare_servers = 2
    pm.max_spare_servers = 6
    rlimit_files = 131072 
    rlimit_core = unlimited
    chdir = /
```

Nginx fascgi configuration part

```
    location ~ \.php$                                                             
      {                                                                             
      fastcgi_index index.php;                                              
      include fastcgi_params;                                               
      fastcgi_connect_timeout 120;                                           
      fastcgi_send_timeout 600;                                             
      fastcgi_read_timeout 600;                                             
      fastcgi_buffers 8 256k;                                               
      fastcgi_buffer_size 256k;                                             
      fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;                                       
      fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;                                    
      client_max_body_size 20M;                                             
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;     
      #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;                                          
      fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    }
```

```
    # strace -f -s 8000 -p 12761
    Process 12761 attached - interrupt to quit
    epoll_wait(9, {}, 1, 944)               = 0
    epoll_wait(9, {}, 1, 1000)              = 0
    epoll_wait(9, {}, 1, 1000)              = 0
    epoll_wait(9, 269f530, 1, 1000)         = -1 EINTR (Interrupted system call)
    --- SIGCHLD (Child exited) @ 0 (0) ---
    write(6, "C", 1)                        = 1
    rt_sigreturn(0x6)                       = -1 EINTR (Interrupted system call)
    epoll_wait(9, {{EPOLLIN, {u32=15427040, u64=15427040}}}, 1, 122) = 1
    read(4, "C", 1)                         = 1
    wait4(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 127}], WNOHANG|WSTOPPED, NULL) = 12826
    write(3, "[21-Aug-2013 19:33:37] WARNING: [pool www] child 12826 exited with code 127 after 275.844033 seconds from start\n", 112) = 112
    clone(Process 12832 attached (waiting for parent)
    Process 12832 resumed (parent 12761 ready)
    child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7fd7a31cfa10) = 12832
    [pid 12832] set_robust_list(0x7fd7a31cfa20, 0x18) = 0
    [pid 12832] dup2(1, 2)                  = 2
    [pid 12832] close(3)                    = 0
    [pid 12832] dup2(7, 0)                  = 0
    [pid 12832] geteuid()                   = 0
    [pid 12832] setrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE, {rlim_cur=128*1024, rlim_max=128*1024}) = 0
    [pid 12832] setrlimit(RLIMIT_CORE, {rlim_cur=RLIM_INFINITY, rlim_max=RLIM_INFINITY}) = 0
    [pid 12832] chdir("/")                  = 0
    [pid 12832] setgid(33)                  = 0
    [pid 12832] open("/proc/sys/kernel/ngroups_max", O_RDONLY) = 3
    [pid 12832] read(3, "65536\n", 31)      = 6
    [pid 12832] close(3)                    = 0
    [pid 12832] open("/etc/group", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
    [pid 12832] lseek(3, 0, SEEK_CUR)       = 0
    [pid 12832] fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=777, ...}) = 0
    [pid 12832] mmap(NULL, 777, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, 3, 0) = 0x7fd7a31c1000
    [pid 12832] lseek(3, 777, SEEK_SET)     = 777
    [pid 12832] fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=777, ...}) = 0
    [pid 12832] munmap(0x7fd7a31c1000, 777) = 0
    [pid 12832] close(3)                    = 0
    [pid 12832] setgroups(1, [33])          = 0
    [pid 12832] setuid(33)                  = 0
    [pid 12832] prctl(PR_SET_DUMPABLE, 1)   = 0
    [pid 12832] close(4)                    = 0
    [pid 12832] close(6)                    = 0
    [pid 12832] rt_sigaction(SIGTERM, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7fd7a02234a0}, NULL, 8) = 0
    [pid 12832] rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7fd7a02234a0}, NULL, 8) = 0
    [pid 12832] rt_sigaction(SIGUSR1, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7fd7a02234a0}, NULL, 8) = 0
    [pid 12832] rt_sigaction(SIGUSR2, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7fd7a02234a0}, NULL, 8) = 0
    [pid 12832] rt_sigaction(SIGCHLD, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7fd7a02234a0}, NULL, 8) = 0
    [pid 12832] rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {0x7633f0, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7fd7a02234a0}, NULL, 8) = 0
    [pid 12832] close(7)                    = 0
    [pid 12832] accept(0,  
    [pid 12761] write(3, "[21-Aug-2013 19:33:37] NOTICE: [pool www] child 12832 started\n", 62) = 62
    [pid 12761] wait4(-1, 0x7fff07258a7c, WNOHANG|WSTOPPED, NULL) = 0
    [pid 12761] read(4, 0x7fff07258b5f, 1)  = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
    [pid 12761] epoll_wait(9, {}, 1, 108)   = 0
    [pid 12761] epoll_wait(9, {}, 1, 1000)  = 0
    [pid 12761] epoll_wait(9, 269f530, 1, 1000) = -1 EINTR (Interrupted system call)
    [pid 12761] --- SIGCHLD (Child exited) @ 0 (0) ---
    [pid 12761] write(6, "C", 1)            = 1
    [pid 12761] rt_sigreturn(0x6)           = -1 EINTR (Interrupted system call)
    [pid 12761] epoll_wait(9, {{EPOLLIN, {u32=15427040, u64=15427040}}}, 1, 769) = 1
    [pid 12761] read(4, "C", 1)             = 1
    [pid 12761] wait4(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 127}], WNOHANG|WSTOPPED, NULL) = 12830
    [pid 12761] write(3, "[21-Aug-2013 19:33:39] WARNING: [pool www] child 12830 exited with code 127 after 10.053632 seconds from start\n", 111) = 111
    [pid 12761] clone(Process 12833 attached
    child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7fd7a31cfa10) = 12833
    [pid 12761] write(3, "[21-Aug-2013 19:33:39] NOTICE: [pool www] child 12833 started\n", 62) = 62
    [pid 12761] wait4(-1, 0x7fff07258a7c, WNOHANG|WSTOPPED, NULL) = 0
    [pid 12761] read(4, 0x7fff07258b5f, 1)  = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
    [pid 12761] epoll_wait(9,  
    [pid 12833] set_robust_list(0x7fd7a31cfa20, 0x18) = 0
    [pid 12833] dup2(1, 2)                  = 2
    [pid 12833] close(3)                    = 0
    [pid 12833] dup2(7, 0)                  = 0
    [pid 12833] geteuid()                   = 0
    [pid 12833] setrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE, {rlim_cur=128*1024, rlim_max=128*1024}) = 0
    [pid 12833] setrlimit(RLIMIT_CORE, {rlim_cur=RLIM_INFINITY, rlim_max=RLIM_INFINITY}) = 0
    [pid 12833] chdir("/")                  = 0
    [pid 12833] setgid(33)                  = 0
    [pid 12833] open("/proc/sys/kernel/ngroups_max", O_RDONLY) = 3
    [pid 12833] read(3, "65536\n", 31)      = 6
    [pid 12833] close(3)                    = 0
    [pid 12833] open("/etc/group", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
    [pid 12833] lseek(3, 0, SEEK_CUR)       = 0
    [pid 12833] fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=777, ...}) = 0
    [pid 12833] mmap(NULL, 777, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, 3, 0) = 0x7fd7a31c1000
    [pid 12833] lseek(3, 777, SEEK_SET)     = 777
    [pid 12833] fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=777, ...}) = 0
    [pid 12833] munmap(0x7fd7a31c1000, 777) = 0
    [pid 12833] close(3)                    = 0
    [pid 12833] setgroups(1, [33])          = 0
    [pid 12833] setuid(33)                  = 0
    [pid 12833] prctl(PR_SET_DUMPABLE, 1)   = 0
    [pid 12833] close(4)                    = 0
    [pid 12833] close(6)                    = 0
    [pid 12833] rt_sigaction(SIGTERM, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7fd7a02234a0}, NULL, 8) = 0
    [pid 12833] rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7fd7a02234a0}, NULL, 8) = 0
    [pid 12833] rt_sigaction(SIGUSR1, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7fd7a02234a0}, NULL, 8) = 0
    [pid 12833] rt_sigaction(SIGUSR2, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7fd7a02234a0}, NULL, 8) = 0
    [pid 12833] rt_sigaction(SIGCHLD, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7fd7a02234a0}, NULL, 8) = 0
    [pid 12833] rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {0x7633f0, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7fd7a02234a0}, NULL, 8) = 0
    [pid 12833] close(7)                    = 0
    [pid 12833] accept(0,  
    [pid 12761]  {}, 1, 766) = 0
    [pid 12761] epoll_wait(9, {}, 1, 1000)  = 0`enter code here`
    [pid 12761] epoll_wait(9, {}, 1, 1000)  = 0
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The above nginx error indicate that issue is related to the fastcgi(php-fpm).

After enabling the "catch_workers_output" on /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf
Got the relevant error on php5-fpm.log.  Now understand that issue is related to AMQP module.

[21-Aug-2013 23:32:57] WARNING: [pool www] child 16091 said into stderr: "php-fpm: pool www: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/php5/20090626/amqp.so: undefined symbol: amqp_open_socket"

Issue has been fixed afterrecompiled and install amqp module

Comment: Having same error. When I enable "catch_workers_output", the php5-fpm.log is not showing any relevent error, only what is in that file is "NOTICE: configuration file /etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf test is successful"

Comment: Same with me...only in my case, i'm getting some IPv6 info as well:  "[error] 1649#0: *17327 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: ::ffff 208.115.111.70 (or 66.192.173.6), server: clmitchell.net, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000:, host: "books.clmitchell.net:, referrer: :http://books.clmitchell.net"

Comment: My IPv6 is My IPv6 addr is 2604:a880:800:10::11b:2001/64

Comment: Enabling `catch_workers_output` shows nothing new. Probably, the reason is somewhere in the opcache.