# 502 Bad Gateway with Zend Debugger (nginx+php5-fpm) and PHPStorm

Tags: php, nginx, phpstorm, zend-debugger

I'm trying to set up the debugging on a server but it won't work.

Here is my setup:

- Nginx with PHP 5.5.9 (fpm, unix socket) @ 192.168.1.40
- Network share with source code @ 192.168.1.50
- The network share is mounted on the webserver at /shared/www/
- My project is located under /shared/www/myProject and get accessed by http://myProject.local/
- Zend Debugger is installed, the following is from the php.ini:

  > zend_extension="/usr/lib/php5/20151104/ZendDebugger-5.5.x-64bit.so"
  >   zend_debugger.allow_hosts=192.168.1.0/24,127.0.0.1
  >   zend_debugger.expose_remotely=always
- The website is working as intended and I don't have problems there.
- My workstation has the IP 192.168.1.10

Now my PHPStorm settings:

#### File -> Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> PHP

- PHP language level 5.5
- Interpreter: 192.168.1.40 (I get correct PHP-Version; Debugger: Zend Debugger, correct configuration file)

#### File -> Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> PHP -> Debug

- Zend Debugger port = 10137
- [x] Can accept external connections

#### File -> Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> PHP -> Server

New server added: 192.168.1.40:80 - Zend Debugger

[x] Use path mappings:
File/Directory: \192.168.1.50\shared\www\myProject

Absolute path on the server: /shared/www/myProject

I've configured zDebug for Chrome this way:

- Debug Host: 192.168.1.10
- Debug Port: 10137
- [x] Check for Zend Debugger Cookie
- [x] Use Fast File
- [x] Debug Local Copy
- [x] Disable Right-Click

---

Now with the config out of the way here is my problem with the debugging:

If I click on "Debug this page" (doesn't matter if I use the [marklets](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/marklets/) or the Chrome extension) the site loades a minute or so and I'm getting a 504 Gateway Timeout from nginx.

Now if I click on the "Start Listening for PHP Debug Connections" (for zero-config debugging) and try the debug again, I'll get instantly a 502 Bad Gateway.

I really have no idea why I'm getting this error. Nginx error logs say this:

> 2015/11/04 18:11:05 [error] 4613#0: *107 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.1.10, server: 192.168.1.40, request: "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "192.168.1.40"

If I disable the debugging there is no error at all.

Does someone has any ideas about this problem? I've searched all PHPStorm documentation but to no avail.

Thank you!

Comment: did you solve this? i'm having a similar problem: php7.0-fpm, xdebug, nginx works fine until i start debugging, then i get 502 errors with "recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream"

Comment: No, I wasn't able to solve it. I switched to XDebug and I'm still happy with this move.

Comment: [Enabling `catch_workers_output`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18379323/failed-104-connection-reset-by-peer) may provide additional info (says *[Zend Debugger] Not connected!* in my case)

Comment: I'm having the same issue now with nginx, xdebug and PHPStorm on Ubuntu.